# adding banner ads to collectionView ios

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview, iad

I'm working with ads for the first time,i want to iAd (banner ad) to collection bottom.But what happened is ad is scrolling along with collection view how to make it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make smaller `UICollectionView` and put iAd view at the bottom of screen(Add iAd view to parent of `UICollectionView`). Your `UiCollectionView` should have `height=UICollecionViewHeight-iAdViewHeight` to make iAd View visible